# How to position div so that its bottom aligns with the top of its containing div

Tags: css

Trying to use CSS to position a div such that:

a) It appears outside of its containing `div` (which I can do) and,

b) the bottom edge of the `div` is adjacent to the top edge of its containing `div` (which I'm struggling with).

Visually, the end result should be that the div appears to be sitting on top of its containing `div`, like the following diagram:

[image]

NOTE: The height of `div` "A" in the diagram varies based on its content, so setting its "top" property to "-150px" or some other negative constant won't work. I'm also trying to avoid JS, but will use it if I can't achieve this with CSS alone.

Sample code:

```
<body>
    <div id="div-B" style="
         position: absolute;
         top: 200px;
         left: 200px;
         height: 200px;
         width: 200px;
         background: red;
         ">
        <div id="div-A" style="
         width: 150px;
         background: green;
         ">
            This is a bunch of text. This is a bunch of text. This is a bunch of text. This is a bunch of text. This is a bunch of text. This is a bunch of text.
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: SO wants code, not pictures. It's not dumb, it's sensible. Post what you've tried.

Comment: Sample code added, @isherwood. Not sure how much it adds to my question, but it's there.

Comment: Adding your code makes it easier for the people trying to help you and it makes it easier for you to describe the problem that you are trying to solve.  Very often, you can get a one or two up votes for presentation, a bit like gold stars from the teacher! Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

For the following **HTML**:

```
<div id="div-B">
    <div id="div-A">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
```

apply this **CSS**:

```css
#div-B {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#div-A {
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 210px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ZM4tT/

Use absolute positioning to move `#div-A` out of the flow of `#div-B` and to the top by setting the box offset `bottom` to either 100% or the pixel height of `#div-B`.

I created a 10px offset to illustrate the control that you have.

**Note** that if `#div-A` has enough text, its height could extend out of the view port and some of the content would not be visible.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Marc Audet. Exactly what I needed. I'd vote your answer up, but I'm still too much of a SO virgin, apparently.

Comment: You are very welcome! I think that 15 reputation points gives you up vote privilege.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` for div "A", but here is more comfortable way > [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDPbS/)

Comment: Thanks, but in your example, div B does not contain div A, which is necessary for my application.